# JWT and PHP: Validating a passed token (Lcobucci\JWT)

Tags: php, jwt

I am attempting to learn how to pass a JWT token from ReactJS to my PHP API. I have 2 functions currently: the authentication function to check the username and password and then generate and pass back a token. The generation part seems to work, but when I pass the token back in the Authorization Bearer, I can't get it to validate. I am using the Lcobucci\JWT library.

Here is my code:

```
 public function attempt_login($input){
            $time = time();
            $token = (new Builder())->issuedBy('https://api.example.com')
            ->permittedFor('https://example.com') 
            ->identifiedBy('4f1g23a12aa', true) 
            ->issuedAt($time) 
            ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($time + 60) 
            ->expiresAt($time + 3600) 
            ->withClaim('uid',1) 
            ->getToken(); 
            return $token;
    }

    public function find($headers){
        $auth = $headers['Authorization'];
        if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $auth, $matches)) {
            $token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $matches[1]);
            $data = new ValidationData();
            $data->setIssuer('https://api.example.com');
            $data->setAudience('https://example.com');
            $data->setId('4f1g23a12aa');
            dd($token->validate($data));
        }else{
            dd('nope');
        }
    }
```

When I dump and die, I always get false. I am 95% sure I am doing it all wrong, but can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: What if you try changing your `canOnlyBeUsedAfter` to just `$time`?

Comment: That worked like a charm! (I think) :)

Comment: I'll move it into an answer then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are checking for validity right away, you would need to change

`canOnlyBeUsedAfter($time + 60)`

to simply

`canOnlyBeUsedAfter($time)`

Otherwise you need to wait 60 seconds before it becomes valid.